# Most efficient "isRelated" function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a nested javascript object (tree) that looks something like this:

```
{
  name: 'something',
  value: 46,
  children: [{
    name: 'child',
    value: 5
  }, ...],
  parent: {
    name: 'parent',
    value: 90
 }
}
```

And I want to have function that I can pass in two objects to see if they are related (parent or child) in this nested tree object.

For example:

```
isRelated(something, parent) => true
```

Is there any type of algorithm that could perform this kind of lookup? Please let me know if I can clarify my question any further. Any help is much appreciated!!!

UPDATE: Here is what I have:

```
function isChild(thing, relative) {
  if (thing === relative) {
    return true;
  }
  if (!thing.parent) {
    return false;
  }
  return isChild(thing.parent, relative);
}

function isParent (thing, relative) {
  var i;
  if (thing === relative) {
    return true;
  }
  if (!thing.children) {
    return false;
  }
  for (i=0; i < thing.children.length; i++) {
    if (isParent(thing.children[i], relative)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function isRelated(thing, relative) {
  return (isChild(thing, relative) || isParent(thing, relative));
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I'm not looking for a more efficient way of writing the same thing, but a more efficient way of traversing the tree to see if two objects are related.

Comment: Anything wrong with a dummy loop with check?

Comment: Is this a tree structure?

Comment: please don't favorite your own questions without a good reason, it doesn't make them more popular and you get notifications about activity on them anyways without favoriting

Comment: unless you improve the structure of the object (or, better, just use a normal tree of objects), there is no very efficient way to do this

Comment: Yes, this is a tree structure.